# moment().toObject() output format

Tags: javascript, format, momentjs

I'm using MomentJS and currently `moment().toObject()` outputs

```
{
years:2016,
months:10,
date:3,
hours:18,
milliseconds:85,
minutes:26,
seconds:26
}
```

How can I change the output format to be

```
{
year: 2016, //without 's'
month: 10, //without 's'
day: 3, // instead of date
...
}
```

Comment: I would create another object and copy the renamed properties using simple js: eg: `newObject.day = momentObject.date`. You can also create a new field like: `momentObject.day = momentObject.date` and then delete the old field using `delete momentObject.date`.

Answer (score 1):

Just build a new object:

```
var a = moment().toObject();
var b = { year: a.years, month: a.months + 1, day: a.date };
```

Note that I incremented the months to account for moment outputting months 0-11 instead of 1-12.  You may or may not want that, but thought it may be useful to point out here.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for a built in way but that will do the job.